# Monogame UWP - Including a DLL library causes error

Tags: c#, dll, uwp, monogame

I'm creating a Monogame UWP Project and whenever I make a call to an included very basic compiled DLL .NET Core library within the project it throws the Error: Could not load file or assembly System.Runtime 4.1.0.0

Here is the project Sample:
http://www.filedropper.com/game1_2

Is everyone else getting the same Error? How do I go about fixing this issue?

Kind regards, Josh L.

Comment: The Error Image: [Error Image](https://imgur.com/a/wQeWV)

Comment: Did you follow this tutorial https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/game_development/monogame/platforms/uwp/ ?

Comment: Yes, I have read that tutorial and it does not cover including external libraries.

Comment: What is your CLI version?

Comment: You cannot reference a full .NET assembly from a UWP project. It'll have to be a PCL, targeting .NET Core (or really just a native DLL without any dependencies). UWP is inherently unmanaged. This time around, C# is the odd one out.

Comment: Your ClassLibrary1 is targeting .NET standard 1.6, not .NET Core.

Comment: IInspectable you are indeed correct, thanks a bunch for your help everyone I'm able to include a PCL LIbrary fine now.

Answer (score 0):

As @iinspectable said in the comments:

> You cannot reference a full .NET assembly from a UWP project.

UWP is a thing on it's own, and is basically incompatible with .NET as it needs to run on all Win10 platforms (where .NET is meant to be run on Windows PC). Now i don't know monogame, but if it's a .NET Library, it's incompatible with UWP.

Comment: @iinspectable you should've posted it as an answer, so Langerz could have validated it. I don't have the rep to comment on the OP, so i put it myself in the answers. feel free to edit what you think is innacurate.